# SQL Server trigger affect 1 row in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am new to triggers and am having a bit of a problem. I am trying to create a trigger to add the new inserted value of 90 in table `sales` to the the total sales for id 100 in salesYTD in table `internetServices`. It seems to do the calculation correctly but it is only suppose to affect the row with the id of 100. Sadly it seems to be changing it for every `salesYTD`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger
ON Sales
AFTER INSERT As
    UPDATE InternetServices
    SET SalesYTD = (SELECT SUM(Amount)
                    FROM Sales
                    WHERE ServiceID = 100)
    WHERE ServiceID = 100;
GO

Print 'Master table Before Insert'
Select * From InternetServices
Print 'After Insert'
INSERT INTO Sales VALUES( 11, '2012-11-14' , 90 , 100 );
Select * From InternetServices
```

Not sure if I gave enough information this is my first time posting a SQL question. Please don't rate down just let me know and I will update it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INSERTED table`. so its add the inserted amount(in table sales) to existing amount in 
`column SalesYTD` of `table InternetServices` .

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger
ON Sales
AFTER INSERT AS
   BEGIN
      UPDATE ITS
      SET SalesYTD = ITS.Amount + I.Amount
      FROM InternetServices ITS
      JOIN INSERTED I ON ITS.ID = I.ID              
   END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `where` clause for the `update`, not just in the subquery:

```
UPDATE InternetServices
    SET SalesYTD = (SELECT SUM(Amount)
                    FROM Sales
                    WHERE ServiceID = 100
                   )
    WHERE ServiceID = 100;
```